# Find a translation that fixes the graph of cosine function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, functions, trigonometry

> Find a translation that fixes $y=\cos x$

That is, the goal is a translation of the plane that fixes this curve:

[image: cosine]

I have tried this numerous times but can't seem to find a method of doing it.
The [article on translation](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Translation.shtml) says it has no fixed points, which confuses me. How can it fix the curve, if it does not fix any point?

Comment: Translation does not fix any point of the real line, but it still can fix values of cosine.  Think about how cosine repeats.

Comment: The translation by a nonzero $x$ increment can fix the curve $y=\cos(x)$ without fixing any single point.  That is, the translation of the curve is the same curve; the translation of each point is a different point.

Comment: I do not understand the close votes here. The question is *not* unclear, and the link is no issue because the OP summarizes their issue with it.

Answer (score 5):

Move it by $2\pi$ to the right.

Yes, the translation itself (unless by zero vector) has no fixed points. It is about the *graph* of your function, it won't have fixed point either under the translation, but the translated points together will give exactly the same graph.

$$\cos(x-2\pi)=\cos(x)$$